# Quicksort with last element as pivot not sorting

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

I have an assignment to create a quicksort algorithm which chooses the last element as the pivot element. Further inside the partition() function when an Element n is found which is greater or equal to the pivot the function should perform a "ring swap". It should swap n with pivot-1 and after that pivot-1 with pivot.

So i wrote this program:

```
int partition(uint8_t *arr, int left, int right){
int pivot_position = right;
if (right-left >1)
{
    for (int i = right; i >= left; i--)
    {
        for (int j = left; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] >= arr[i])
            {
                pivot_position = i;
                int tmp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i-1];
                arr[i-1] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = tmp;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    if (right-left == 1 && arr[left] > arr[right])
    {
        int tmp = arr[left];
        arr[left] = arr[right];
        arr[right] = tmp;
    }
    return 0;
}

return pivot_position;
```

}

```
void quicksort( uint8_t *arr, int left, int right){
int pivot = partition(arr, left, right);

if (pivot != 0)
{
    quicksort( arr, left, pivot-1);
    quicksort( arr, pivot+1, right);
}
```

}

If given the Array: [160, 32, 96, 128, 224, 64, 192, 0, 255]
The expected Output: [0, 32 , 64 ,96, 128, 160, 192, 224, 256]

What have I done wrong?

EDIT:
As requested:

```
void main() {
uint8_t *arr = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*9);

arr[0] = 160;
arr[1] = 32;
arr[2] = 96;
arr[3] = 128;
arr[4] = 224;
arr[5] = 64;
arr[6] = 192;
arr[7] = 0;
arr[8] = 255;

for(int i = 0; i < 9, i++){
    printf(arr[i]);
}
quicksort(arr, 0, 8);

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    printf(arr[i]);
}
}
```

Sorry if this does not work coudnt test it I am currently not infront of my machine.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: And while you're at it, provide hardcoded input in your [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are not always comparing with the pivot value. Your code assumes it is at `i`, but that will not be true once the `j` loop doesn't find anything to swap. In that case your outer loop will still decrease `i`, which at that moment no longer points to the pivot.

Also when you update `pivot_position`, you should take into account that you are about to *move* that pivot to index `i-1`, so it should take *that* value.

Then there is also a type issue. You've declared `arr` as a pointer to `u_int8`. But then your `temp` should not be defined as an `int` but as `uint8_t`.

If we just want to fix the *minimum* necessary, you could replace this:

```
        if (arr[j] >= arr[i])
        {
            pivot_position = i;
            int tmp = arr[left];
```

with this:

```
        if (arr[j] >= arr[pivot_position])
        {
            pivot_position = i-1;
            uint8_t tmp = arr[left];
```

But the double loop is inefficient. The inner loop starts from `left` over and over again. This is not needed. You only need to compare a value once with the pivot. Also, when there are only two values to partition, you don't really need a special case (the `else` block).

Also,

Here is how I would write it -- using that 3-cycle constraint:

```
int partition(uint8_t *arr, int left, int right) {
    // right will be the pivot index
    while (left < right) {
        if (arr[left] >= arr[right]) {
            uint8_t tmp = arr[left];
            arr[left] = arr[right-1];
            arr[right-1] = arr[right]; // Pivot value
            arr[right] = tmp; // Current value
            right--; // Adjust pivot index
        } else {
            left++; // The value is in the correct partition, so move on 
        }
    }
    return right; // Return pivot index
}
```